# ¿como puedo hacer para separar numeros impares y pares despues de haber utilizado el algoritmo "bubble sort"?

Tags: javascript

he creado este código, pero no se si lo tengo bien:

```js
function bs(arr, first, second){ 
    var temp = arr[first]; 
    arr[first] = arr[second]; 
    arr[second] = temp;
}

function bso(arr){
    var leng = arr.length,
        i, x, stop;
    var pares;
    var impares;

    for (i=0; i<leng; i++){
    for (x=0, stop=leng-i; x<stop; x++){
            if (arr[x]>arr[1+x]){
                bs(arr, x, 1+x);
                if (i%2!=0) {
                pares.add(arr);
                } else {
                impares.add(arr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
document.getElementById("burbuja").innerHTML = bso([82, 52, 5, 8, 100, 67]);
document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = pares;
document.getElementById("impar").innerHTML = impares;
```

```html
<h1>Orden Normal:</h1>
<h1 id="burbuja"></h1>
<br>
<h1>Números Pares:</h1>
<h1 id="par"></h1>
<br>
<h1>Números Impares:</h1>
<h1 id="impar"></h1>
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour]y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: No está bien porque no inicializas los arrays y estás usando add en lugar de push para introducir elementos en los mismos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

        <h1>Orden Normal:</h1>
        <h1 id="burbuja"></h1>
        <br>
        <h1>Números Pares:</h1>
        <h1 id="par"></h1>
        <br>
        <h1>Números Impares:</h1>
        <h1 id="impar"></h1>

    <script>

        var pares=[];
        var impares=[];

        function bs(arr, first, second)
        { 
            var temp = arr[first]; 
            arr[first] = arr[second]; 
            arr[second] = temp;
        }

        function bs(arr, first, second)
        { 
            var temp = arr[first]; 
            arr[first] = arr[second]; 
            arr[second] = temp;
        }

        function bso(arr)
        {
            var leng = arr.length,i, x, stop;

            for (i=0; i<leng; i++)
            {
                for (x=0, stop=leng-i; x<stop; x++)
                {
                    if (arr[x]>arr[1+x])
                    {
                        bs(arr, x, 1+x);
                    }
                }
            }

//PUEDES DESPUES DE TERMINAR EL ORDENAMIENTO INSERTARLOS EN LOS ARREGLOS PARES E IMPARES
            for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                if(arr[i]%2==0) //PARA LOS PARES
                {
                    pares.push(arr[i]);
                }
                else //PARA LOS IMPARES
                {
                    impares.push(arr[i]);
                }
            }

            return arr;
        }

        document.getElementById("burbuja").innerHTML = bso([82, 52, 5, 8, 100, 67]);
        document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = pares;
        document.getElementById("impar").innerHTML = impares;
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Obtendrias lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te ayude. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function bs(arr, first, second){ 
    var temp = arr[first]; 
    arr[first] = arr[second]; 
    arr[second] = temp;
}

function bso(arr){
    var leng = arr.length,
        i, x, stop;
    var pares;
    var impares;

    for (i=0; i<leng; i++){
       for (x=0, stop=leng-i; x<stop; x++){
            if (arr[x]>arr[1+x]){
                bs(arr, x, 1+x);
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

let result =bso([82, 52, 5, 8, 100, 67]);

document.getElementById("burbuja").innerHTML = result;
   // filtramos el arreglo para pares;
document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = result.filter(x=> x%2==0);
// filtramos el arreglo para impares; ;
document.getElementById("impar").innerHTML = result.filter(x=> x%2!=0) ;
```

```html
<h1>Orden Normal:</h1>
<h1 id="burbuja"></h1>
<br>
<h1>Números Pares:</h1>
<h1 id="par"></h1>
<br>
<h1>Números Impares:</h1>
<h1 id="impar"></h1>
```